# Why is Travis rebuilding successful builds?

Tags: travis-ci

I'm looking at https://travis-ci.org/ZotPlus/zotero-better-bibtex/builds/64379824 (green) and https://travis-ci.org/ZotPlus/zotero-better-bibtex/builds/64380301 (red). Both build the same github commit, so I can't have caused this with a push.

Comment: Recently they have had some issues - see [here](https://www.traviscistatus.com/incidents/vhml8d5bs1q1)

Comment: That page says it's resolved shows as resolved, and I just had it happen again.

Comment: It is as a matter of fact structurally rebuilding my release builds. I commit something to a different submodule as part of the release, but don't check in the main module. It is also not a new build -- the same SHA1 is being rebuilt, and Circle doesn't rebuild when I execute the same procedure.